# how to group sub elemnts using spring batch staxeventitemwriter and jax2bmarshaller

Tags: spring-batch

I need to generate XML like the below.`enter code here`

XML

[image: XML]

I have used `StaxEventItemWriter` and `jax2bmarshaller` create simple XML but not able to create sub elements

By using `@XMLRootElement` is it possible to create sub elements to the root element tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use headercallback and footercallback in staxeventitemwriter to set the static content.it's worked for me.